# trying to load a video element with nodejs. Getting Error: Not implemented: HTMLMediaElement.prototype.load

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

Trying to render a mp4 video with jsdom and fabric

```
const object = new (cls || Media)(videoElement, options);
            object.set("url", url);
            object.set("__options", options);
            videoElement.loop = true;
            const onSeeked = () => {
                videoElement.pause();
                // middle frame loaded and we can play
                // now we can return ready video
                callback && callback(object);
                resolve(object);
                videoElement.removeEventListener("canplay", onSeeked);
            };
            const onLoad = () => {
                // Wait for video to load
                videoElement.addEventListener("canplay", onSeeked);
                // Seek middle frame - for sake of paused preview
                // we will get result after another canplay event
                videoElement.currentTime = videoElement.duration * 0.5;
                videoElement.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
                videoElement.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
                videoElement.removeEventListener("canplay", onLoad);
                videoElement.load();
                videoElement.play();
            };
            videoElement.addEventListener("canplay", onLoad);
            videoElement.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
                callback && callback(null, true);
                reject(e);
            });
            source.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
                callback && callback(null, true);
                reject(e);
            });
            videoElement.load();
```

Since this is server side nodejs I am using jsdom to createDOM elements.
Once it reaches videoElement.load() It gives the following error. I looked up jsdom architecture and it seems they dont support video mp4 load and play

Getting Error:
 `Not implemented: HTMLMediaElement.prototype.load`

**UPDATED:**
I was able to get video frames with ffmpeg library but now how can i generate the video on a canvas with node?
[current implementation with ffmpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q9wL.png)

Comment: I mean this is pretty clear, no? `Not Implemented` is not really the same as `undefined`, the devs know this is part of the spec but have not implemented it. It is possible, since its server side, that creating an element there will automatically load it (as its not like it can wait for user interaction). But there must be better ways to get a video frame than using a virtual DOM.

Comment: Yes with ffmpeg I was able to get video frames but my requirement is to create apng files from the .mp4 files. That also i can do. Now I am stuck on how to render these frames on a node canvas to generate a apng

Comment: Do you have a buffer for the frame?

Comment: Technically I was able to extract video frames to files. But My use case is to extract all the frames and draw them on canvas with ctx.drawImage()

Comment: Does this have to be server side? There are probably modules that can help you, but node does not support canvas standard. If you can do it client-side, its a lot easier.

Comment: Yup it has to be server side. We are generating apng files from a canvas. Its a gif maker app with multiple assets. Doing it in client side is easy but since we are integrating into a third party app local downloads are not permitted.